# Does SonarQube support JSONP?

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, jsonp

I'm working on a WebApp which cannot retrieve data from the SonarQube server because the browser complains that `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. After searching the recommended way to overcome this error is to use `JSONP` or `CORS`. I'm unable to find documentation regarding JSONP callbacks. Is this feature part of the SonarQube server?

**Alternative solution I found to solve this problem**

Going with a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to process API requests and serve it with CORS headers.
Using the [`cors-anywhere`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) package to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get data from a remote SonarQube server and serve it in a web application, the only way for the moment is to fetch it on backend side and then pass the result to your frontend.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail please? If I'm running an Angular app in Node, do you mean that Node has to fetch the json from Web APIs?

Comment: I mean that the code which does the WS calls must not run in the Web browser, otherwise you will hit the same origin issue.

Answer (score -1):

**NOTE:** for below ways you will require CROSS ORIGIN POLICTY ALLOW

there is way to fetch SonarQube data remotely.

1. you can try fecthing data by CURL.
   e.g curl -u MY_LOGIN:MY_PASSWORD https://sonarqube.com/api/user_tokens/search

   - replace your sonarqube sever details it will fetch data of list of user tokes for user.
2. if you are using node server with angular js, you can write module with basic authentication will hit apis you want.
   refer doc: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2752802
   e.g - to fetch list of project on system api is 
   http://yourservername/api/resources

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This doesn't seek to answer my original question "Does SQ support JSONP?" This is a question mainly about the internals of SQ and partly about CORS (which I'd already solved via a hack as mentioned in the question).